# Check if a ToggleSwitch is on

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I know it must be a silly thing, but I can't find how to check if a ToggleSwitch is on.
This is my code:

```
    private void ToggleNamePrivacy_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ToggleNamePrivacy.IsOn == true)
        {
            PrivacyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/public.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            PrivacyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/private.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

The if clause is causing a

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Neither is working if I write:

```
if(ToggleNamePrivacy.IsOn)
```

Why?

Comment: Is ToggleNamePrivacy null?

Comment: ToggleNamePrivacy is the x:Name of my ToggleSwitch:
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="ToggleNamePrivacy"                           x:Uid="ToggleNamePrivacy"                           Toggled="ToggleNamePrivacy_Toggled" IsOn="True" />

Comment: you don't need the `== true` its redundant

Comment: Is the ToggleSwitch defined in a Template or is it a direct child/grandchild of the page?

Comment: Either way: Put this in the first line of your event handler: var ToggleNamePrivacy = (ToggleSwitch)sender;

Comment: When and where the code is being invoked? For example if it's being invoked before `InitializeComponent()` - then your switch will be null. Have you tried to debug your code? Can you also show more code - xaml definition/subscription?

Comment: Adding the "var ToggleNamePrivacy = (ToggleSwitch)sender" worked but now I have another problem: any item in the page seems to be null: http://i.imgur.com/bLaC9cD.png. The exception happens as soon as I tap the button to navigate into the page. How can I invoke it later?

Comment: So strange: the tapped event is working, and the toggled is crashing: http://i.imgur.com/ZRdWDy3.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: it must be a bug, but you can't set both the "IsOn" property and the "Toggled" event in the XAML or the IsOn will trigger the Toggled event before the page loads.

Not working:

```
<ToggleSwitch Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled" IsOn="True" />
```

Working:

```
<ToggleSwitch Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled" />
```

(you can then set the IsOn via code.)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug, hence it's working as it should - the property values are set just after the constructor, before `InitializeComponent` has ended. Hence you **are** changing the property and the switch is Toggled -> the event is fired (still `InitializeComponent` hadn't ended). Either change `IsOn` or subscribe to the `Toggled` event after `InitializeComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have the scope right or it wouldn't compile. Where is the method getting called from? If it is before InitializeComponent() then it will be null. I'd just check for null at the beginning of the method and return, since it is probably just being called on the initial set when the app first starts up.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are having the same problem where the toggle is in a ListViewItem/GridViewItem or so. Just subscribe to the Toggle's `Loaded` event in XAML and inside it Subscribe to `Toggled`.
In XAML:

```
<ToggleSwitch Loaded="ToggleSwitch_Loaded" />
```

And in C#

```
  private void ToggleSwitch_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ToggleSwitch toggle = (ToggleSwitch)sender;
            toggle.Toggled += ToggleSwitch_Toggled;
        }

  private void ToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Your logic
        }
```